# How to set inner object Data property for a datagridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have created Entity Framework for a model.
I would like to access inner object and bind that inner object to a datagridview.
I can access inner object but i cant set data property of datagridview to show this.
Can any one please help me out
Here the code
I have two classes in EF.
ItemMaster And Category.ItemMaster Contains Category Id.Category Contains Category Name.
now in EF i can access Category Object like

```
 public static List<ItemMaster> GetAllItemMasters()
 {
 using (var itemContext = new EntitiesContext())
 {
        var items = itemContext.ItemMasters.Include("Category").Where(p=>  (p.IsDelete==   null || p.IsDeleted.Value == false)).ToList();
        return items;
    }
```

now while binding to a datagridview i have only properties like categoryid
in code behind i can access inner object like itemmaster.category.categoryname
but i cant set data property of datagridview as category.categoryname.
So can you please help me out

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to your namespace (if needed), then unbox the item into the parent class.

```
((MyClass)Container.DataItem).MyInnerClassObject.SomePropertyValue
```

Comment: @RoopeshPm - Post your code.  I need to see the class you're binding to and the markup where the binding occurs.  Thanks.